# How to make named data.frame object in the list instead of using default numeric index?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I wrote my custom function for performing setdiff operation for list of data.frame object recursively. Now my custom function return list of unnamed data.frame object. However, I want each data.frame  in each list must have name with very specific order. I aware that few changes must be needed in my custom function in order to return named data.frame object in each list. I tried to assign name for them, but that was not elegant to do. How can I get my expected output ? Can anyone propose possible idea to fix and improve the code in custom function ? FYI, all data, custom function, desired output are simulated.

data:

```
myList <- list(
  foo = data.frame( start=seq(1, by=4, len=6), stop=seq(3, by=4, len=6)),
  bar = data.frame(start=seq(5, by=2, len=7), stop=seq(7, by=2, len=7)),
  bleh = data.frame(start=seq(1, by=5, len=5), stop=seq(3, by=5, len=5))
)
```

I coded this custom function :

```
library(dplyr)

func <- function(list, idx=1L) {
  entry <- list[[idx]]
  self_ <- setdiff(entry, entry)
  res <- lapply(list[-idx], function(ele_) {
    joined_ <- setdiff(entry, ele_)
    joined_
  })
  result <- c(list(self_), res)
  return(result)
}
```

output of my custom function are:

```
res_1 <- func(list = myList, idx = 1L)
res_2 <- func(list = myList, idx = 2L)
res_3 <- func(list = myList, idx = 3L)
```

I expect my custom function must explicitly indicate name of data.frame in each list by very different order instead of default numeric index.

desired output:

```
res_1 <- list(foo=data.frame(), bar=data.frame(), bleh=data.frame())
res_2 <- list(bar=data.frame(), foo=data.frame(), bleh=data.frame())
res_3 <- list(bleh=data.frame(), foo=data.frame(), bar=data.frame())
```

How can I achieve my desired output? Is there any smart way to fix the problem in my custom function? How can I make this happen? Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, you could do: `idxs=1:3; lapply(idxs, function(x) myList[seq_along(myList)[ order(seq_along(myList) != x) ]])` but I suspect there is not a good reason to permute a list of data.frames...

Comment: @Frank: Could you elaborate about using "=" operator in the list instead of using <- ? Why?

Comment: In `x = list(a = 1, b = 2)`, list is a function and a and b are argument names. We pass argument names only with `=`. Passing argument names is a distinct task from assignment. For assignment, I could do `x = 1` or `x <- 1`; but when passing args to a function, only `=` works.

Comment: I need to think about your comment, please keep it here, or publish an answer for further usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other commentators have pointed out, you need to use an `=` rather than an `<-` to assign named elements to your list, ie

```
myList <- list(
  foo = data.frame( start=seq(1, by=4, len=6), stop=seq(3, by=4, len=6)),
  bar = data.frame(start=seq(5, by=2, len=7), stop=seq(7, by=2, len=7)),
  bleh = data.frame(start=seq(1, by=5, len=5), stop=seq(3, by=5, len=5))
)
```

Once you have done that you can get the results you want by adding one line to your function

```
func <- function(list, idx=1L) {
    entry <- list[[idx]]
    self_ <- setdiff(entry, entry)
    res <- lapply(list[-idx], function(ele_) {
        joined_ <- setdiff(entry, ele_)
    })
    result <- c(list(entry), res)
    names(result) <- c(names(list[idx]),names(list[-idx]))
    return(result)
}
```